# Using toUppercase directly vs replace then toUppercase

Tags: javascript, string

I found a code that changes a String to uppercase.

```
const s = 'Keep on Asking'
const r = s.replace(/[a-z]+/g, function(m) {
 return m.toUpperCase() 
})
console.log(r)
```

**Output: 'KEEP ON ASKING'**

What I usually do instead:

```
const s = 'Keep on Asking'
const r = s.toUpperCase()
console.log(r)
```

**Output: 'KEEP ON ASKING'**

Can someone explain why the first method is used? Is it bad practice to just directly use toUppercase function?

Comment: That does seem very odd, as it will specifically break accented words with its `naïve` approach to the alphabet...

Comment: I'd use the second - `r = s.toUpperCase()` - simple enough and straight forward.  
I'm no expert on regex (for example: I don't know what the `+` is for).
Unless someone can "prove" that using regex is in any way better, I see it as scratching your left ear with your right hand - when the left hand is right there! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the avoidance of doubt: Just use `toUpperCase` or [`toLocaleUpperCase`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.tolocaleuppercase) directly, don't use that first code block without a really good (and likely obscure) reason.

The first code block will **only** change the English letters `a` to `z` to upper case, leaving other letters (like `à`) alone. In contrast, [`toUpperCase`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.touppercase) handles vastly more characters because...

> The result must be derived according to the locale-insensitive case mappings in the Unicode Character Database (this explicitly includes not only the UnicodeData.txt file, but also all locale-insensitive mappings in the SpecialCasings.txt file that accompanies it).

(That's from [`toLowerCase`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase), which `toUpperCase` refers to.)

Here's that difference in action:

```js
const original = "voilà";
console.log(
    "replace just a-z:  " +
    original.replace(/[a-z]+/g, m => m.toUpperCase())
);
console.log(
    "toUpperCase:       " +
    original.toUpperCase()
);
console.log(
    "toLocaleUpperCase: " +
    original.toLocaleUpperCase()
);
```

So unless the person using that first code block just didn't understand what they were doing, they must have wanted to only change those 26 English letters if they were present and leave others alone. I couldn't say why, but note that *sometimes*, `toUpperCase` (and `toLocaleUpperCase`) can change the length of a string. Perhaps that had something to do with it.

Here's an example of the length changing:

```js
const original = "Straße"
const capped = original.toLocaleUpperCase();
console.log(`original (${original.length}): ${original}`);
console.log(`capped (${capped.length}):   ${capped}`);
```

Comment: I see. So unless you're trying to apply some condition, the second method is the way to go

Comment: @SeoiMin - I *just* added a new first paragraph before you commented, because I realized I'd not been clear about that. :-) Yes, the second way is the correct and standard way to do it, using `toUpperCase` or `toLocaleUpperCase` directly, not using `replace` to pick out only certain characters.

Comment: "*toUpperCase can change the length of a string*"–An example would be when using the German Eszett "ß". Uppercasing the word "Straße'" (length 6) returns "STRASSE" (length 7).

Comment: @str - Thank you! The spec just mentioned that it could happen and I couldn't think of an example. (Which is a bit sad, since a few years ago I *did* run across the ß => SS thing unrelated to programming...)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why the first method is used? Is it bad practice to just directly use `toUppercase` function?

It is not a bad practice to directly use `toUppercase` function. In fact, I would say the first approach is a bad practice because:

- It only affects non-accentuated Latin letters.
- It is slower because it first needs to match the RegEx to the string.

I have no idea why someone would use the first method for practical purposes.